# Evento Click en Li Html

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net, asp

Tengo este código en Html

```
<li class="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
                            Transportistas
                        </a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                            <li> <a href="#" id="repo1" runat="server" onclick="MySql"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i>Reporte 1</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#" id="repo2" runat="server" onclick="MySql"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i>Reporte 2</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#" id="repo3" runat="server" onclick="MySql"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i>Reporte 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

y quiero que me al presionarlo me traiga un evento en C# este es el código

```
protected void MySql(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        repo1.Visible = false;
        repo2.InnerText = "PHP";
    }
```

Comment: Para lo que quieres te recomiendo usar ajax con jQuery. Por suerte hay muchísima documentación: http://www.yogihosting.com/calling-a-c-function-with-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tienes que tener en cuenta una cosa. Si utilizas AJAX no vas a tener acceso a `repo1` ni `repo2` ya que la llamada AJAX tiene que hacerse en el ámbito de un `[WebMethod]` (método estático) y dicho ámbito queda fuera del ciclo de vida de la página. Es decir, en el momento de la llamada al `[WebMethod]` los controles de tu página `repo1` y `repo2` no existen y por tanto no puedes acceder a ellos.

El flujo sería más bien así:

1. Tu `javascript` llama a un `WebMethod` del servidor a través de `AJAX`.
2. El `WebMethod` no modifica nada, sólo devuelve una serie de datos.
3. El `javascript` modifica el `DOM` de tu página con los datos obtenidos.

Volviendo a tu ejemplo, imagina que quieres cambiar el texto de `repo1` por un dato obtenido de servidor (te pongo un ejemplo utilizando `jQuery` que te facilita mucho las cosas):

```
[WebMethod]
protected static string MySql()
    {
        return "PHP";
    }
```

Y en tu `Javascript`:

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "tuPagina.aspx/MySql",
                        data: '', //Parámetros a enviar al método si los tuviera
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json", //Tipo de datos enviados
                        success: function(response) {
//En caso de que todo vaya bien obtienes aquí la respuesta (string "PHP")
});
```

De todas formas, visto tu código, no necesitas llamar al servidor. Con hacer esto valdría (siguiendo con `jQuery`):

```js
$(".active").on("click",function(){
//Llamamos a la función parent para obtener el "li" anterior y ocultarlo.
 $("#repo1").parent().hide(); 
  $("#repo2").html("PHP");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
                            Transportistas
                        </a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                            <li> <a href="#" id="repo1" runat="server" onclick="MySql"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i>Reporte 1</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#" id="repo2" runat="server" onclick="MySql"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i>Reporte 2</a></li>
                            <li> <a href="#" id="repo3" runat="server" onclick="MySql"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i>Reporte 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```